# Stopping Application Loop in secondary AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, asynchronous, appdomain

First off, apologies for the length...

I have a Host/Plugin application akin to MAF. We are not using any of the System.Addin or associated namespaces as this is a custom plugin architecture with multiple AppDomains in play. The Host UI (user interface) is running in it's own application loop (AppDomain). When an item in a listview is double-clicked the following occurs:

```
private static void StartPeripheralModule(string modName)
{
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(modName);
    // add to appdomains collection
    HostDomains[modName] = domain;

    // instances the module for access to the module's Start() method
    IModule module = (IModule)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    ModuleManager.Modules[modName].Name, 
    ModuleManager.Modules[modName].EntryPoint.FullName);

    // instance the adapter (inherits MBR)
    module.Adapter = new ModuleAdapter(modName, module);  // also saves a ref. to the IModule object

    // publish events decorated with [Serializable]
    module.Adapter.ModuleStarted += new ModuleAdapter.ModuleStartEventHandler(Adapter_ModuleStarted);
    module.Adapter.ModuleStopped += new ModuleAdapter.ModuleStopEventHandler(Adapter_ModuleStopped);
    module.Adapter.ModuleFaulted += new ModuleAdapter.ModuleFaultEventHandler(Adapter_ModuleFaulted);

    // add to adapters collection
    HostAdapters[modName] = module.Adapter;

    // asynchronous startup
    Action startup = module.Start;
    startup.BeginInvoke(null , null);
}
```

In the `module.Start()`:

```
[STAThread]
public void Start( )
{
    //  do Start
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MdiForm = new UnitMDIForm();
    MdiForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(MdiForm_FormClosed);

    adapter.OnModuleStarted(new ModuleAdapter.ModuleStartEventArgs(adapter));

    Application.Run(MdiForm);
}
```

`MdiForm_FormClosed` simply tells the Host that the module plugin is being closed via the plugin's UI and to begin closing procedures on the `AppDomain`. The module plugin starts as expected and the event `OnModuleStarted` works fine. When the listview item is once again double-clicked the module should shut down:

```
public static void UnloadInstance(string modName)
{
    Action shutdown = HostAdapters[modName].Module.Shutdown;
    IAsyncResult iaRes = shutdown.BeginInvoke(null , null);

    while (!iaRes.IsCompleted)  // poll wait state
    {
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        hostListener.Write(".");
    }
}
```

Shutdown function in module plugin:

```
public void Shutdown( )
{
    if (MdiForm.InvokeRequired)
    {
        MdiForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            MdiForm.FormClosed -= MdiForm_FormClosed;
            Application.Exit();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        MdiForm.FormClosed -= MdiForm_FormClosed;
        Application.Exit();
    }

    adapter.OnModuleStopped(new ModuleAdapter.ModuleStopEventArgs(adapter));
}
```

The reason the MdiForm.FormClosed event is unsubscribed to is to prevent double firing. As soon as the `Application.Exit()` I get 1 - 2 '.' (dots) from the polling mechanism and then:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in UnitTestWinForm.dll 
>   An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in UnitTestWinForm.dll but was not handled in user code

Needless to say, we never reach our `OnModuleStopped` event where we officially unload the AppDomain and remove it and the adapter from our collections. I am putting a try/catch block in now to see if I can get anything more from the errors. From what I understand, I am following the proper procedure in exiting the application message loop and then unloading the domain. This gives the module the ability to clean up it's resources, etc.

**Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and/or how I should do this differently?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help...

In your app, subscribe to:

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;
        Application.ThreadException += ApplicationThreadException;
```

(see the help, they may make things easier but other times in debug mode you'll want this off)

I don't think you should be calling Application.Exit() from the module, it will (as far as I know) shut down the whole app.

Perhaps look at how A tool like NUnit loads and unloads AppDomains - I have never tried unloading one....

PK  :-)

Comment: @Paul: I'll try and see what happens. Since the module is running in it's own AppDomain, then Applicatin.Exit() should be fine, AFAIK.

Comment: @Paul: It turns out that I could have a larger threading issue than I thought. But it doesn't make sense if this is the case because where it appears to be getting hung should be on the main thread of the main AppDomain. :/ Still working on this...

Comment: Marking as the answer. I did some more testing and calling the AppDomain.Unload(...) is causing an issue. This will be a new question.

Comment: Cool - well, as in it helped!!

Comment: @Paul: All in all it caused me to do some trimming. Apparently I am doing something wrong because AppDomain.Unload(..) on a child domain *should not* affect the main application's domain. :( Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294474/appdomain-unload-killing-parent-appdomain

Comment: And my threading issues came because I was asynchronously attempting to stop the child application...yuck!!! No need to do that.