# AppDomain Unload killing Parent AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, appdomain

I am having trouble figuring something out about my `AppDomain.Unload(...)` call. I have a detailed explanation with code from [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293290/stopping-application-loop-in-secondary-appdomain). As it turns out, I was performing a couple of steps that apparently, I don't need to. However, I am fairly certain that when an AppDomain is created and then held in a collection:

```
private static Dictionary<string , AppDomain> HostDomains;

void StartNewDomain(string domainName)
{
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(domainName);
    HostDomains[domainName] = domain;
}
```

...when you are done with it, you must unload it:

```
if (HostDomains.ContainsKey(domainName))
{
    AppDomain.Unload(HostDomains[domainName]);
    HostDomains.Remove(domainName);
}
```

then remove domain from the collection.

When I unload the domain, however, the entire application is ending. If I remove the unload, all is well...and we are simply left with removing the domain from the collection. But I fear that my child AppDomain is *not* really unloaded. It may eventually get GC'd I guess, but that doesn't give me a warm fuzzy.

The child AppDomain assembly (a Windows Form application) is started asynchronously via an interface (IModule) that is referenced in my adapter class which inherits `MarshalByRefObject`. I am wondering if this reference to IModule's Start() (which the plugin module assembly implements) is not marshaling properly (because of my implementation). So, when the Shutdown() method is called, the entire application dies. Should I make my IModule an abstract class instead so it should inherit MBR as well? Puzzled...

After looking at my code:

```
// instances the module for access to the module's Start() method
    IModule module = (IModule)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    ModuleManager.Modules[modName].Name, 
    ModuleManager.Modules[modName].EntryPoint.FullName);
```

...my fear is that since IModule is an interface, even though I am creating an instance in a child domain, the assembly is leaking into my main AppDomain. Therefore, when I attempt to unload the child domain, both domains are being unloaded. Would this be correct? And what would likely be the best solution to provide Start() & Stop() methods via the MBR (adapter) object?

UPDATE: see my answer below for changes --
Okay, there is no leaking -- everything inherits MBR:

1. Host : MarshalByRefObject -- instances the ModuleAdapter in a new AppDomain
2. ModuleAdapter : MarshalByRefObject --  IModule interface, interface methods (Start,Stop)
3. MyModulePlugin : MarshalByRefObject -- Application.Run(myForm)

Am I doing something wrong still? I've tried several things and it just seems to be wrong or incomplete. When I tell the ModuleAdapter to shutdown, it calls `AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain.CurrentDomain)` and the Host domain stops as well. I am still getting some first chance exceptions on the application exit. But the form (myForm) has been told to .Close().

So, I am still looking for the correct way of doing this...

Comment: My guess is it has to do with you starting winform in the child appdomain... Why don't you start the winform in default domain. I think Once UI main thread exits app will end. Look at raymond chen's blog.

Comment: @Fakrudeen: I would like to look at the blog without searching...do you have a link?  ;)

Comment: Be sure to hookup to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledExceptionHandler also to check what tears down your domain.

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen: I'll keep that in mind. Since I made my answer community wiki, you can edit ...I believe (dep. on rep). If you do add it, go into a bit of detail on implementation. Since MEF has been introduced, I've used that framework instead. But, I still like the way I was implementing a Host that communicated with Modules by remoting across app domains ... e.g. serialized messaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, instancing with the IModule interface in the primary domain causes a leak. In order to do this properly:

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(domainName);
HostDomains[domainName] = domain;  // put in collection

ModuleAdapter adapter = (ModuleAdapter)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(asmName , typeName);
```

where ModuleAdapter inherits `MarshalByRefObject`. Then:

```
adapter.Execute(moduleAssembly , moduleType);
```

Inside the ModuleAdapter class:

```
public void Execute(string Name, string EntryPoint)
{
    module  = (IModule)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Name , EntryPoint);
}
```

I do welcome comments or additional answers for a better way.

After moving the instancing to the ModuleAdapter class, we are still having the issue with AppDomain.Unload killing the entire application. I was wondering if this is because in the module plugin we are using `Application.Run(myForm)` - then when we shutdown we call myForm.Close(). Obviously this shuts down the application so I was wondering if the myForm.Close() also 'unloads' the AppDomain.

Comment: You are correct about the leak. Using an interface will not prevent the primary assembly from deserializing the full implemented type. Also, make sure your primary application isn't closing due to a ThreadAbortException, which will be rethrown continually if not properly reset.