# AppDomain unloading closes application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have pretty simple code like:

```
var childDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("child");
childDomain.ExecuteAssembly("WpfApplication1.exe");
AppDomain.Unload(childDomain);
```

But it closes app at all. I don't have any references to WpfApplication1.exe in parent app. I read this - [AppDomain Unload killing Parent AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294474/appdomain-unload-killing-parent-appdomain) but it hadn't helped.

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check  if any exception is thrown that crashes the process?

Comment: Just a question, do you really need to create this app domain manually yourself ? You could well do a simple Process.Start() to run your external app which will creates appdomain of its own right.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel , how I can do this? I would like to have some control over child domain. For example catch exceptions, set thread principles and etc.

Comment: I'm not sure you can handle the exceptions of another app domain. You can subscribe to `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event, but it will anyway terminate the process. I'm providing a hint to you so that you can find what takes your process down,

Comment: I subscribed to this event but it has never been raised

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in this line:
childDomain.ExecuteAssembly("WpfApplication1.exe");

ExecuteAssembly method runs application on the same thread as caller. So unloading is killing the main thread. The solution is run child app in new STA thread.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I was unloading an appdomain created on the main thread and wondering why the application terminated. Didn't know that unloading the appdomain would will the thread that created it.